# How can you module.export a single object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to map the pages from the config.js file to be used within my nav.js component but am having trouble trying to access the data from the config.js file. When I check the export module in the console, it returns as undefined and I have no idea where I am going wrong. I have tried `default export` and `module.exports` so far, I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding the whole concept entirely.

**Config.js file**

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    home: {
      link: '/',
      title: 'Home'
    },
    about: {
      link: '/about',
      title: 'About'
    },
    workshops: {
      link: '/workshops',
      title: 'Workshops'
    },
    contact: {
      link: '/contact',
      title: 'Contact'
    }
  }, 
  info: {
    company: 'Roadworks Media'
  }
}
```

**nav.js file**

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import config from '../data/config'

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <nav role="menubar" aria-expanded='false' className="hidden md:block">
      {config.pages.map((page, index) => {
        return <Link key={index} href={page.link}><a className="px-4" aria-label={page.title}>{page.title}</a></Link>
      })}
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Comment: You are exporting the object correctly (using commonjs). `pages` does not have a map method (only arrays do). Instead try changing `pages` to an array, or use `Object.values(config.pages)`?

Comment: Why are you combining [CJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (`module.exports`) and [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (`import`, `export`)?

Comment: Oh I see, didn't realise they were unrelated. Thanks, will check out those links @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Have a read through the two linked sections above. Basically, they're two different ways of doing modules, CJS is Node.js's way from before JavaScript had a standard module syntax, and ESM is the standard syntax. For new projects, etc., I suggest the standard syntax unless you have a strong reason to use CJS. With ESM you don't use `module.exports` at all, you use `export`. For instance, to create a named export, you'd do `export const pages = {/*...*/};` and import it as `import { pages } from "./your-module.js";` Or you can use a default export.

Comment: (FWIW, I cover this in my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys* in Chapter 13. :-) Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: Problem solved, thank you both very much, this has been very helpful :)